# Clicking on "Real Name" gets an empty list

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, user-accounts

If I click on *Real Name* reported for an account, I am taken to a page that is supposed to list all the users who entered the same real name.

Doing it, for example, for my account takes me to a page showing no name.

> [image: screenshot]

I reached that page clicking on a link.

> [image: screenshot]

I didn't enter two spaces in my real name, so the software is not looking for`alberto paderno` when it should look for `alberto  paderno`.

What happens with my account happens for all the accounts. It seems the software is using the real name to look for usernames, which is not expected.

Comment: Maybe case sensitive? Did you try with proper case too?

Comment: The text is already pre-filled after you click on the link; if you enter _Alberto Paderno_, it is changed to lowercase.

Comment: So weird. So bug indeed, maybe case sensitive behind the scenes, maybe wrong field being searched... hope a dev will come over and fix it soon. :)

Comment: It could be, even if the same is done for the username, and it finds users.

Comment: The user search route has always (far as I know, anyway) accepted a display name but not a real name. IIRC the real name column in the DB doesn't get the same treatment as the display name (we store the lowercase version as well, for example, which simplifies the lookup), so making it work for real names is a bigger undertaking that I'm not sure is actually necessary. In other words, while it might be worth expanding the route to cover real name as well, perhaps, the immediate fix here is to not create the link in the first place.

Comment: @AdamLear I would think that being able to find any users entering the same real name would be much helpful, since users know most of the users  don't see it. If somebody would create a sockpuppet account, they would not use the same display name again. Indeed, removing the link would be a quick fix. At least it doesn't get to an empty page.